# Suggestion: suppress green upvote indicator in topbar

Tags: feature-request, achievements-dialog, top-bar

Currently, users with an account get the upvotes to their answers reported via a small greenish thing with the number of such upvotes. It gives a pop-up window with links to the answers (or questions I don't recall now). The only way I know of to get rid of the upvote indicator is to click on it (which displays the useful pop-up window, allowing to quickly go back to one's own recent upvoted answers and check if others have contributed answers too in the meantime).

Thus, as far as I know this thing is sticky until clicked on it. It would be nice if that indicator were to silence itself after say 6 hours.
In this way, the registered users would less be under influence of the recompense circuits in his/her brain when connecting to the site. This would make for a saner relationship with the site.

My preference would be for the total suppression of this indicator: only the pop-up window would be retained.

Comment: This is a network-wide feature: I suspect you might be best raising on the central meta (though I also suspect you'll get told 'status bydesign').

Comment: I asked new question there http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286936/allow-user-to-customize-or-even-suppress-reputation-indicator

Comment: @JosephWright if you need some distraction go check how welcomed my suggestion has been. It does feel like a warm and open-minded site !

Comment: Now you know why the review system is broken: those people designed it :)

Comment: Excuse me for asking, but why is it so annoying to you? I hardly see it!

Comment: @CarLaTeX I can only take note of how annoying it was to me. Explaining is hard, perhaps I am particularly sensitive to a green rectangle on a black background which will not go away until I explicitly make the move to click on it, move which triggers a drop-down menu which perhaps I didn't want to see at this time. Now that this past story, I don't fear anymore scrolling back up to top of window. I just don't like unwanted solicitations such as marketing over the phone, pop-up windows, etc.. and would not at all browse the internet were it not for AdBlockPlus and similar tools.

Comment: @CarLaTeX add to this that I don't like the idea of the site making statistics of what I do on the site, how prompt I will react to appearance of an upvote notification etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will repeat here the tip obtained at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286939/344080

I edited my `/chrome/userContent.css` in my Firefox profile to contain:

```
@-moz-document domain(tex.stackexchange.com) {

    .topbar .icon-achievements { display: none !important; }

}
```

This suppressed indeed the green rectangle.

---

Here are further questions on the top meta site, a few years back, which are somewhat related to the spirit of my question:

[How to disable/remove all badges and reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40777/how-to-disable-remove-all-badges-and-reputation)

[Options to hide reputation info on StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11586/options-to-hide-reputation-info-on-stackoverflow)

[Hide the rep and badge count on a user's info box on answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21458/hide-the-rep-and-badge-count-on-a-users-info-box-on-answers)

---

In the spirit of the above I have now completed my `/chrome/userContent.css` like this:

```
@-moz-document domain(tex.stackexchange.com) {

    .topbar .icon-achievements { display:none!important; }

    .topbar .topbar-links .topbar-flair { display:none!important; }

    .user-info .-flair { display:none!important; }

/* needed for "Top questions" */

    .started .reputation-score { display:none!important; }

}
```

Firebug came quite handy to identify the relevant css elements, although in retrospect the css is not obfuscated thus human logical deduction would have been possible.

I now benefit from a sanitized view, much to my satisfaction.

As I primarily spend (at some periods in the year) my time on the `tex.stackexchange.com` sub-domain, I did not bother experimenting with other domains. It does work here on meta.tex.stackexchange.com, hence presumably using `domain(stackexchange.com)` would work universally, not tested yet. (because I need to quit and relaunch Firefox, afaik, to let it know about the new userContent.css)

<strike>*yes, I confirm* `domain(stackexchange.com)` *works universally*</strike> not quite because not everything is subdomain of `stackexchange.com`, for example http://stackapps.com

Not being knowledgeable in other systems/browsers I am sorry I can't provide detailed instructions beyond the above.

For the time being I will accept this answer, of course I will move the tick to any better answer should one come up in future.